# Remove all nodes which don't lie in any path with sum >= k

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

> Given a binary tree, a complete path is defined as a path from root to a leaf. The sum of all nodes on that path is defined as the sum of that path. Given a number *K*, you have to remove (prune the tree) all nodes which don't lie in any path with sum >= *k*.
>
> Note: A node can be part of multiple paths. So we have to delete it only in case when all paths from it have sum less than K.

The question is attributed to GeeksForGeeks.  I'm looking for code-review, best practices and optimizations.

```
public class PrunePathWithLesserSum {
    
    private TreeNode root;
    
    public PrunePathWithLesserSum(List<Integer> items) {
        create(items);
    }
    
    private void create (List<Integer> items) {   
        if (items.size() == 0) {
            root = null;
        } else {
            root = new TreeNode(items.get(0));
        }
        final Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
        queue.add(root);

        final int half = items.size() / 2;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
            if (items.get(i) != null) {
                final TreeNode current = queue.poll();
                final int left = 2 * i + 1;
                final int right = 2 * i + 2;

                if (items.get(left) != null) {
                    current.left = new TreeNode(items.get(left));
                    queue.add(current.left);
                }
                if (right < items.size() && items.get(right) != null) {
                    current.right = new TreeNode(items.get(right));
                    queue.add(current.right);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static class TreeNode {
        private TreeNode left; 
        private int item;
        private TreeNode right;
        
        TreeNode(int item) {
            this.item = item;
        }
    }


    public void prune(int val) {
        if (root == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The root cannot be null");
        }
        if (!recurse(root, 0, val)) {
            // if no patch exists then prune the root.
            root = null;
        }
    }


    public boolean recurse(TreeNode node, int sum, int value) {
       if (sum >= value) return true; 
        
       if (node == null) return false; 
        
       boolean left = recurse (node.left, sum + node.item, value);
       boolean right = recurse (node.right, sum + node.item, value);
        
       if (!left) {
           node.left = null;
       } 
       if (!right) {
           node.right = null;
       }
       return left || right;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hashCompute(root, 0);
    }
    
    private int hashCompute (TreeNode node, int item) {
        if (node == null) return item;
        item = 31 * hashCompute (node.left, item) + node.hashCode();
        return hashCompute(node.right, item);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        PrunePathWithLesserSum other = (PrunePathWithLesserSum) obj;
        return equal(root, other.root);
    }

    private  boolean equal(TreeNode node1,  TreeNode node2) {
        if (node1 == null && node2 == null) return true;
        if (node1 == null || node2 == null) return false;
        if (node1.item != node2.item) {
            return false;
        }
        return equal(node1.left, node2.left) && equal(node1.right, node2.right);
    }
}


public class PrunePathWithLesserSumTest {
    
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        PrunePathWithLesserSum ppwls1 = new PrunePathWithLesserSum(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));
        ppwls1.prune(10);
        PrunePathWithLesserSum ppwlsExpected1 = new PrunePathWithLesserSum(Arrays.asList(1, null, 3, null, null, 6, 7));
        assertEquals(ppwlsExpected1, ppwls1);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test2() {
        PrunePathWithLesserSum ppwls2 = new PrunePathWithLesserSum(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));
        ppwls2.prune(100);
        PrunePathWithLesserSum ppwlsExpected2 = new PrunePathWithLesserSum(Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
        assertEquals(ppwlsExpected2, ppwls2);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test3() {
        PrunePathWithLesserSum ppwls3 = new PrunePathWithLesserSum(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));
        ppwls3.prune(0);
        PrunePathWithLesserSum ppwlsExpected3 = new PrunePathWithLesserSum(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));
        assertEquals(ppwlsExpected3, ppwls3);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`value` doesn't change across invocations of `recurse()`, so passing it down doesn't look right. Instead you may pass a deficit (`value - sum`), decrementing it by a `node.item` value. One less argument to `recurse()`.